# Authentication parameters missing in postman for api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

Each time I try to authenticate with api.ai I receive a 401 Unauthorized error.

I am using postman and I have tried both my Client access token and Developer access token. Neither seem to work.

This is the body that I am attempting to send:

```
{
    "query": [
        "hi"
    ],
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "lang": "en",
    "sessionId": "1a63011b-0eb7-4f0e-b75a-7dc0fa67a8b0"
}
```

[Screen shot of the postman POST attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BsHp.png)

What could be causing the authentication error?

Comment: Hi, I worked on something similar recently in one of my tasks and I had to provide <AUTHENTICATION> as part of the body, but yes I got to know about that because I had the spec for the same. In case you have a spec please check the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Check your url(https://api.api.ai/api/query?v=20150910). It should be: https://api.api.ai/v1/query?v=20150910

Answer (score 0):

There are two query types GET and POST.
https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/query#get_query

While using postman. I tried POST it worked.
Choose option POST and put this URL (https://api.api.ai/v1/query?v=20150910)
under the Header option.

1. Create Authorization Key like

   key-> Authorization and the value -> Bearer xxxx

where x is your client access token.

2. Set content type application/json

   key - > Content-Type and the value -> application/json
   Header part is over.

Body. (raw JSON)

```
{   "query": "hi",
 "lang": "en",
 "sessionId": "1234567890"}
```

then send it will work. 
Note: Body object should have at-least these fields to work.